# TypeScript: reduce function - No overload matches this call

Tags: arrays, typescript

Trying to write a basic reducer to return an array of (value of) a key from an array of objects. Some of the key can be missing or undefined.

My code:

```
const data = [{Key: 56}, {Key: undefined}, {}, {Key: 44}]

const keys = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (curr.Key) {
    return [...prev, curr.Key];
  } else return prev;
}, []);
```

It works fine as a plain JS but the TS compiler does not like it. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gaQKYCeAXDAKwBsAvgDQy6EkCuYceAZgJZh5w11-1iMACzDKAXQBQk0JFgBrQhDTwkCAHQAnHo2B4AFPoAO2gG61gjTZoCUaAHx1JMGBzYx9l6+vwE7WZxcYbSgrMEx1SJM8cxgvTR9CcQBuQMoYPAAbCDxgvFDNcOjTVL4McRtkoA)

How to fix this? mainly what am I doing wrong? I am a TS noob.

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.  

Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }, currentValue: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }, currentIndex: number, array: ({ Key: number; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]) => { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; }, initialValue: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; }): { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; }', gave the following error.  
Argument of type '(prev: never[], curr: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }, currentValue: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }, currentIndex: number, array: ({ Key: number; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]) => { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; }'.  
Types of parameters 'prev' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.  
Type '{ Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.  
Type '{ Key: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.  
Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: never[], currentValue: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }, currentIndex: number, array: ({ Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; })[]) => never[], initialValue: never[]): never[]', gave the following error.  
Argument of type '(prev: never[], curr: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: never[], currentValue: { Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; }, currentIndex: number, array: ({ Key: number; } | { Key: undefined; } | { Key?: undefined; })[]) => never[]'.  
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.  
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign the type of the accumulator (`[]`) as `number[]` ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gaQKYCeAXDAKwBsAvgDQy6EkCuYceAZgJZh5w11-1iMACzDKAXQBQk0JFgBrQhDTwkCAHQAnHo2B4AFPoAO2gG61gjTZoCUaAHx1JMGBzYx9l6%20vwE7WZxcYbSgrMEx1SJM8cxgvTR9CcQBuQMoYPAAbCDxgvFDNcOjTVL4McRgEZTBGAFsAIzxNcptkoA)):

```
const keys = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (curr.Key) {
    return [...prev, curr.Key];
  } else return prev;
}, [] as number[]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the type of the second argument of `reduce` function.

Try this

```
const data = [{key: 56}, {key: undefined}, {}, {key: 44}]

const keys = data.reduce((keys, current) => {
  if (current.key) {
    return [...keys, current.key];
  } else return keys;
}, [] as number[]);
```

Edit: I rushed the answer before, also to improve the readbility of the code, I suggest you to make some changes, like name the property `key` instead of `Key`, and some better naming for the parameters of the `reduce` function